# Generators of cobordism algebra of involutions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

My question is about Boardman's five-halves theorem. In lemma 4.2

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-27/issue-2/Stabilizations-of-periodic-maps-on-manifolds/10.1307/mmj/1029002360.full)

the author refers to a paper of Boardman in which generators of $MO_*(BO)$ are constructed. In this paper only generators $(t,M^n)$ where n is not of the form $2^s-1$ occur. The same is in the book of Conner and Floyd 'Differentiable periodic maps'. In Royster's paper lemma 4.2 (ii) however, it is stated that there is a generator for every n. My question is why it suffices to construct generators only for $n \neq 2^s-1$.
I know this is pretty vague but i hope that somebody is familiar with this statement.

Best regards.